# Change name of category heading in legend

Tags: qgis

In QGIS 2.8.1, I have a SHP layer. In the display it is categorized by one of the fields, "Sannsynlig". In the table of layers and in the legend, it is also identified as "Sannsynlig", as the name below the main layer name ("Faresoner"). However, I would like to have it displayed as "Sannsynlighet". Is it possible to change the name in the legend and in the table of layers?

[image: Sannsynlig]

Answer (score 1):

You can either rename the layer in the layer panel and then add the legend into a composer again (so the changed name is used) or you can follow [this manual](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#adding-a-legend-item-to-the-print-composer) that should answer your question as well.

Comment: Thank you, but I still cannot change the group name. This goes for the composer as well as in the table of layers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [QGIS Docs](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html), you can edit the legend item name via the Properties dialog for the legend item in the composer.

> The legend will be updated automatically if checkbox Auto-update is
>   checked. When Auto-update is unchecked this will give you more control
>   over the legend items. The icons below the legend items list will be
>   activated.
>
> The legend items window lists all legend items and allows you to
>   change item order, group layers, remove and restore items in the list,
>   edit layer names and add a filter.
>
> - The item order can be changed using the [Up] and [Down] buttons or with ‘drag-and-drop’ functionality.
> - The order can not be changed for WMS legend graphics.
> - Use the [Add group] button to add a legend group.
> - Use the [plus] and [minus] button to add or remove layers.
> - **The [Edit] button is used to edit the layer, groupname or title. First you need to select the legend item.**
> - The [Sigma] button adds a feature count for each vector layer.
> - Use the [filter] button to filter the legend by map content, only the    legend items visible in the map will be listed in the legend.
> - After changing the symbology in the QGIS main window, you can click    on [Update All] to adapt the changes in the legend element of the
>     Print Composer.